# building an image from Mat object in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

Im using OpenCV and I have a Mat object of size 1024*1024(extracted from a photo and manipulated) and the values are in the range [1..25].for example:

```
Mat g;
g=[1,5,2,14,13,5,22,24,5,13....;
21,12,...;
..
.];
```

I want to represent these values as an image.It is only an illustration image to show the different areas,each area with a color.
For example: all the values that equals 1=red, all the values that equals 14=blue, and so on..

and then construct and display this photo.

Anybody have an idea how should i proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are [colormaps](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html) , but they won't help if your data is in the [0..25] range only. so you probably ned to roll your own version of that:

```
   Vec3b lut[26] = { 
        Vec3b(0,0,255),
        Vec3b(13,255,11),
        Vec3b(255,22,1),
        // all the way down, you get the picture, no ?
   };

   Mat color(w,h,CV_8UC3);
   for ( int y=0; y<h; y++ ) {   
       for ( int x=0; x<w; x++ ) {
           color.at<Vec3b>(y,x) = lut[ g.at<uchar>(y,x) ];   
          // check the type of "g" please, i assumed CV_8UC1 here. 
          // if it's CV_32S, use g.at<int>  , i.e, you need the right type here 
       }
   }
```

Comment: @berak..thanks so much this code works perfectly. Although i had to choose the elements values of 'lut' manually using suitable pixels values, but it is ok as long as it works fine. When i tried to use colormaps i had a black image and i don't know why.maybe it is because of the type of Mat or something else but no problem i used the other way anyway. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not too fussed what colors you get, you can scale your data (so it almost fills the 0 to 255 range) then use an inbuilt colormap.
e.g.

```
cv::Mat g = ...
cv::Mat image;
cv::applyColorMap(g * 10, image, COLORMAP_RAINBOW);
```

See the [applyColorMap() doco](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html#applycolormap)

Comment: I tried it but i get a black image when i try to use colormaps i don't know why..thanks anyway :)

Comment: @triple13 The rainbow colormap  doesn't even contain black so you have done something really wrong.

Comment: Yes i know. The problem i think is the type of my Mat, because if i load a normal image using `imread` and then apply colormaps it works fine